# What is the Python equivalent of R function gg_miss_fct?

Tags: python, r, missing-data

In R, gg_miss_fct get missing value percentage with one heatmap, how can I get that in equivalent for python?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHr7X.png)

Answer (score 0):

using pandas and seaborn you can do it like this, where data is a pandas dataframe.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
sns.heatmap(data.isna().transpose(),
        cmap="YlGnBu",
        cbar_kws={'label': 'Missing Data'})
plt.show()
```